Shortest path to all nodes from a center point, repeats allowed
I'm trying to create an algorithm to figure out a path visiting every single node in a graph (undirected and unweighted) - similar to the traveling salesman problem, but I can visit a node multiple times. I can't use brute force mainly because there's 299 nodes.
Furthermore, this is special because every point is connected to every other point - there's 44551 paths. I've seen people recommending the Floyd-Warshall algorithm to help optimize each node pair connection, but I don't think it applies in this case because each point is already connected to every other point.
If anyone can tell me how to start, that would be great! Or if someone can help me modify an existing TSP algorithm to solve this problem. Also, Python is the language I'm using, mainly because of the networkx library
Edit: forgot to mention that I don't need to only make roads to the nodes - for example, if nodes 1, 2, and 3 form an equilateral triangle, TSP says the shortest distance is to go from 1-2-3-1 along the edges, but I can use Fermat Points to make the distance smaller (3 units vs sqrt3 units) - sorry if this sounds a bit incoherent

https://stackoverflow.com/q/39833023/781723

Please don't use "Edit: [more stuff]".  Instead, revise your question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time, and contains all information in the logical order.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755

On first take, I read unweighted as unit distance/cost - but then, where was the problem? So if every edge has it's own length, how shall I interpret unweighted? Using additional points, this does not read graph - is it planar geometry?

The answer from StackOverflow:

The typical approach is to create a distance matrix that gives the
shortest-path distance between any two nodes. So d(i,j) = shortest
path (following the edges of the network) from i to j. This can be
done using Dijkstra's algorithm.
Now just solve a classical TSP with distances d(i,j). Your TSP
doesn't "know" that the actual route followed might involve visiting a
node multiple times. At the same time, it will ensure that the vehicle
stops at every node.
Now, as for efficiency: As @Codor points out, TSP is NP-hard and so is
your variant of it, so you are not going to find a provably optimal,
polynomial-time algorithm. However, there are still many, many good
algorithms (both heuristic and exact) for TSP, and most of them should
be suitable for your problem. (In general, DP is not the way to go
for TSP.)

